# How to get my post types in the menu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 custom post types - offered and wanted.  I want these items in my menu.  How can I do this?

I have tried adding a category to the post type and then creating a link to that category but for some reason that isn't working.

Someone else has said to give my custom posts an archive and have all the posts showing in that archive.  Ok, but I'm not sure how to create an archive for my custom post, especially as I'm not using pretty URLs because it wouldn't work with my custom posts, so had to put it back to the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the `register_post_type()`

```
'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
```

Also check the 'screen options' in the top right corner. that 'Custom Links' are checked.

Usually you can get to the 'acrhive' of a custom post type via exapmle.com/customposttype
if perma is enabled and the posttype has `'has_archive' => true,`
To add this to the menu you will have to add a custom/hard coded menu item.

Alternatively you can make a theme template page on which you query the custom post type.
In effect making your own archive which will show up in the menu screen as a page.

Comment: The option is there to add individual custom posts to my menu, but not to add the link to show all the individual posts.  I'm wondering if I need to create an archive?

Comment: thanks, I made my own archive as suggested.  Would you be able to check I'm doing my custom post right if I posted you my code?  It's just I know that certains things should only run at certain times, and I'm not sure if my functions.php fileis just setting up a custom post every time the page is refreshed or whatever.  I'm really quite lost.

Comment: don't get it!  One of my custom post types has a working archive, the other one isn't working.  I have set 'has_archive' => 'wanted', and 'has_archive' => 'offered', and created archive-offered.php and archive-wanted.php, but the wanted one doesn't work.  No idea why.

Comment: You need to set `'has_archive' => true,`